# Como combinar dos archivos excel con python y pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo dos archivos Excel, con referencia de productos y precios, muy largo, el otro simplemente contiene las referencias de los productos y debo introducir los precios, el problema es que no todos los productos del primer archivo están en el segundo, si no los ordenaría y copiaría, ¿Cómo puedo buscar el producto en el primer libro y añadir el precio que le corresponde en la columna correspondiente del segundo? Solo he utilizado lo básico con pandas y excel. Así es como leo los archivos y me gustaría combinarlos en uno:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel('oferta.xlsx')
df2 = pd.read_excel('Libro1.xlsx')
print(df1)
print(df2)

df_combine = df1.merge()

df_combine.to_excel('result.xslx')
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si lo realizo mediante filtros como la respuesta de abajo:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel('libro2g.xlsx', index_col=[0])
df2 = pd.read_excel('libro1g.xlsx',  index_col=[0])
print(df1)
print(df2)

df2['precio']=df1[df1['desc'].isin(df2['desc'].tolist())]['precio']


df2.to_excel('result.xlsx')
```

El error es:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\alvar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py",
> line 3080, in get_loc
> return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)   File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 70, in
> pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc   File
> "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 101, in
> pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc   File
> "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 4554, in
> pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item   File
> "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 4562, in
> pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item KeyError: 'desc'
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:\python\code\last.py",
> line 8, in 
> df2['precio']=df1[df1['desc'].isin(df2['desc'].tolist())]['precio']
> File
> "C:\Users\alvar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py",
> line 3024, in **getitem**
> indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)   File "C:\Users\alvar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py",
> line 3082, in get_loc
> raise KeyError(key) from err KeyError: 'desc'

Comment: Cuales serían las columnas que harían match en ambos archivos ? Descripción y descripción breve ?

Comment: Exactamente, también coinciden las columnas nº Mat. Sap ant. seguido de MAT_0000000 con la columna Código.

Comment: Un filtro basta

Comment: un filtro como?

Comment: ahora hago una respuesta y mencioname!

Comment: @Christian ¿por qué siempre pedís que te mencionen o voten tu respuesta sino lo han hecho?

Comment: @tincopasan lo que pasa es que si hay otros comentarios la notificación no llega, por lo que si el usuario quiere preguntarme algo y no me menciona nunca me enteraré \\_(°-°)_/

Comment: podrias subir tu archivo a la nube y colocar un link, quiero revisarlo

Comment: Hola ya lo resolví, gracias.

Comment: Ho me alegro :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno hay una forma sencilla y tradicional de resolver tu problema y es haciendo un *filtro*, es decir solo vamos ha poner el precio si los datos del *df2* estan en el *df1*, donde el `df1` es el que contiene todos los datos y el `df2` solo contiene algunos del `df1`.

Para hacer esto tuve que poner datos ficticios por que no tus datos no estan en la pregunta en formato texto

**creación de DataFrames**

```py
import pandas as pd

col1 = ['producto','precio']
col2 = ['producto','cantidad']
data1 = [['pd1',2],['pd2',4],['pd3',10],['pdx',100]]
data2 = [['pd1',7],['pd2',1],['pd3',2]]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1,columns=col1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2,columns=col2)
```

**df1** (contiene todos los datos)

|  | producto | precio |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | pd1 | 2 |
| 1 | pd2 | 4 |
| 2 | pd3 | 10 |
| 3 | pdx | 100 |

**df2** (solo hay algunos datos del df1)

|  | producto | cantidad |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | pd1 | 7 |
| 1 | pd2 | 1 |
| 2 | pd3 | 2 |

Para hacer el filtro solo necesitamos usar la funcion `isin()` que combrueba si una lista de valores se encuentra en un dataframe

```
df2["precios"]=df1[df1["producto"].isin(df2["producto"].tolist())]["precio"]
```

Con `df2["precios"]` creamos una nueva columna en el `df2` llamada `precios` que contendrá el resultado de `df1[df1["producto"].isin(df2["producto"].tolist())]`, esto nos devolverá un DataFrame (productos, precio que corresponde al `df1`) con solo los valores del `df1` que se encuentren en el `df2` pero como solo nos interesa el precio hacemos `["precio"]`

**resultado `df2`**

|  | producto | cantidad | precios |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | pd1 | 7 | 2 |
| 1 | pd2 | 1 | 4 |
| 2 | pd3 | 2 | 10 |

Para guardar el resultado lo hacemos de la misma forma en que tu lo haces

```
df2.to_excel('result.xslx')
```

Comment: hola, gracias por la respuesta, pero no entiendo como abres los archivos y lo guardas luego?

Comment: Ho. Ahora lo añado

Comment: Ya lo añadí :).

Comment: podrias poner el error?

Comment: he editado la pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Comienza por renombrar las columnas que harán match, dejándolas con el mismo nombre para que pandas pueda identificar correctamente las columnas, hago el ejemplo con la descripción pero te sugiero que lo hagas por las columnas de código

```
df1.rename(columns={"descripcion": "desc"}, inplace=True)
df2.rename(columns={"descripción breve": "desc"}, inplace=True)
```

También recomendable crear indices al hacer el cruce:
`df2.set_index("desc",inplace=True)`

Por ultimo usa `merge` indicando la columna

`df3 = df2.merge(df1, left_index=True, right_on="desc", how='left')`

No tuve oportunidad de probar (por los archivos) pero debería funcionar o al menos darte la idea.

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta, no es el resultado esperado, me crea un archivo que es un lio con todo mezclado, la idea es rellenar el segundo con los datos del primero